# Custom string format from list C#

Tags: c#, json, format

i have a class with a list of data, like this:

```
public List<Data> data;

public class Data {
    public String KEY;
    public String VALUE;
}
```

My question is: How can i get the next format string with data of **`List<Data>`**?

`{"key1":["value1"],"key2":["value2"]}`

I tried with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert but i get this string:

`[{"KEY":"key1","VALUE":"value1"},{"KEY":"key1","VALUE":"value1"}]`

Comment: `String.Format("{{\"{0}\":[\"{1}\"], \"{2}\":[\"{3}\"]}}", key1, value1, key2, value2);`

Comment: @chouaib but is a List, this list have multiples values and keys and i need get all data separated with ","

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to easily use Json.Net, you just need to convert your `List<Data>` to a `Dictionary<string, string>` first:

```
var dict = data.ToDictionary<string, string[]>(d => d.KEY, d => new[] { d.VALUE });
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Comment: yes, but this return `[{"KEY":"key1","VALUE":"value1"},{"KEY":"key1","VALUE":"value1"}]` and i need get `{"key1":["value1"],"key2":["value2"]}`

Comment: Converting to a Dictionary first should prevent that (serializing a dictionary should produce a single JSON object).

Comment: @JustinNiessner, actually it should be `data.ToDictionary(d => d.KEY, d => new[] { d.VALUE })` to produce the desired result.

Comment: I get this error: `System.Collections.Generic.List<Data> not have a definition for 'ToDictionary and the best extension method overload of 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TKey>)' has some invalid arguments.`

Comment: @Manux22 - Sorry. Made an update and forgot to update the generic type parameter. Try again.

Comment: @Manux22 you need to include Linq ... using System.Linq;

Comment: @JuanC. ,  yes, i already have this, `using System.Linq;` but i have the same error :/

Comment: @Manux22 remove this part <string, string[]> from  ToDictionary<string,string[]>

Comment: @JuanC. Thanks!! this works fine now :D  -  Justin Niessner, JuanC., Thomas Levesque, Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

this is an application of "to a man with a hammer, every problem looks like a nail"!
sincerly, Justin's answer is the most suitable, but I don't mind introduce this work around. (P.S: not tested it may need some troubleshooting)

```
private string convertToJSON(list<Data> data)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  string str;
  int i=0;

  sb.Append("{");   // start 
  for(i=0; i<data.Count-1; i++)
  {
    // add each pair of data with a comma
    str = String.Format("\"{0}\":[\"{1}\"], ", data[i].key, data[i].value);
    sb.Append(str);
  }

  // add the last pair of data
  sb.Append("\"{0}\":[\"{1}\"]", data[i+1].key, data[i+1].value);
  sb.Append("}"); // close the sequence

  string Result = sb.ToString(); // resulting string
  return Result;
}
```

Then, just call it like this `string json = convertToJSON(data);`

Comment: Thanks but this solution is "aggressive", first i go to trying with the code of Justin

Comment: definitely should `Accept` justin's answer, but no this is not *aggressive* xD it is just not the *suitable* answer

Comment: but not is this more slower?

Comment: I'd be curious to know which is the slowest method after you try them both with your real data, though I didn't consider that when answered your question which doesn't point that the speed is critical, p.s I don't know `JSON` at all, I am just a `C#` programmer, I try to solve my problems using all what I know about `C#` in most cases